# Why CSS3 columns override each other

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I want to use css3 columns to create horizontal layout.

I've got several horizontal groups of content that should have some spacing between each other and they should not break into new line.

When I put several elements with css columns each next to other, then one group override another (seems like they have 100% width and they dont respect their horizontal expantion by content)

```
<div class="horizontal-groups-wrapper">
    <div class="horizontal-group">...</div>
    <div class="horizontal-group">...</div>
</div>
```

here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fee2G/1/

Expected result:
Each next group with css columns lays nicely after previous group

Actual result:
Each next group overrides previous like it would have smaller width than it really has.

ps. I would rather want to find solution, not workaround as example is totally simple.

Comment: Try removing `whitespace:nowrap;` from .horizontal-groups-wrapper.

Comment: Some color to better illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fee2G/8

Answer (score 3):

Determining the width of the columnized element is tough. I would recommend removing the two columnized `div`s and moving all the content into a single columnized element, then forcing a break before your `h2` elements to get the effect you want using the `break-before` property.

```
h2 {
  -webkit-column-break-before: always;
  break-before: column;
}
```

Here's the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/Q66as/)**.

Comment: In more advanced horizontal layouts it's impossible to manage content keeped in one column. Especially when different gap's / width of columns is needed.

Comment: The entire column spec is still pretty incomplete imo. I've tried to use it on a project and it wasn't worth the workarounds. There are some jQuery plugins that do the job better.